# PictureBox onPaint Clears Every Control

Tags: c#, .net, paint, picturebox, invalidation

I've been having problems with onPaint event handler for a pictureBox. I've simplified the code, so right now I'm trying to achieve this: load the bitmap from path into pictureBox1 and draw a small rectangle around mouse cursor when moving over the pictureBox1.

```
    private int mouseX;
    private int mouseY;
    private String path;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        path = "images\\image.jpg";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(path);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseX = e.X;
        mouseY = e.Y;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, mouseX - 10, mouseY - 10, 20, 20);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
```

When I run the application the bitmap is loaded successfully and the rectangle is being drawn nicely wherever I drag the mouse. Anyway there are two problems:

1) When the Form is loaded everything is white but pictureBox until I move the window somewhere. It means menuStrip, toolStrip eg is cleared with white color. When I add pictureBox.Invalidate(); into Form1_Load it seems to take care of that problem (everything is loaded and visible) but on the toolStrip there are some buttons and comboBoxes that are interacting, changing its visibility and this still causes problems. I'd like to reduce the funcionality of the Paint only on pictureBox.

2) The rectangle is drawn the moment the Form is loaded despite the mouse cursor didn't enter pictureBox. Also when cursor leaves the pictureBox the last drawn rectangle stays there. I've tried to remove it but I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks for any suggestions, it seems to me that something fundamental is missing there but don't know what.

Comment: using `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` in `Paint` event handler is a bad idea because it causes another paint event.

Comment: Consider moving the `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` to the `MouseMove` handler.

Comment: If the rectangle can not keep up with the cursor, replace `Invalidate` by `Refresh`

Comment: Consider invalidating only the area around cursor position in order to increase the performance.

Comment: Also it doesn't seem that the problem with menus has any relationship with the paint event. There is nothing unusual about the paint event. It should only paint the `PictureBox`!

Comment: @yBee Moving Invalidate into MouseMove actually helped with the problem 1), but the other problem stil remains. Using MouseEnter and some condition in Paint causes rectangle to disappear when the Form is loaded, but I can't manage to hide the rectangle that is already drawn. I can redraw it somewhere else but don't know how to erase it.

Comment: @SysGen: In order to erase rectangle you can perform `Invalidate` method with parameter, that will indicate the region of the control to redraw by default background color or you can draw _invisible_ rectangle that will erase that _visible_. In both cases you need to have x and y of previously drawn rectangle. You can get them from `Paint` handler when you are drawing a new rectangle. So `mouseX` and `mouseY` will contain coordinates of the actual rectangle to draw and `prevMouseX`, `prevMouseY` will contain coordinates of currently visible rectangle.

Comment: @SysGen: In `MouseLeave` event handler you should try to invalidate the region occupied by a rectangle using `prevMouseX` and `prevMouseY` coordinates.

Comment: @yBee Thanks, that fixes the problem. But it's kind of weird way to do something like this, not very neat. It seems quite silly to me that there is no other easier way to just clear the graphics that was previously drawn and keep the original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) `MouseMove` works only when cursor is over picture box. Try to use `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` in order to handle when to start drawing rectangle and when to stop doing that.